# Update ComboBox with VBA and multiple WHERE condition SQL

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I try to update a combo box in a Form using VBA and SQL with multiple WHERE conditions. If I use only one condition it works, if I add others it will show no results

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim strSQL As String
If Forms!frmLogin!txtLogin = "some text" Then
strSQL = "SELECT table.field1 FROM table WHERE table.field2=1; "
End If
With Forms!frmForm1!subfrmForm2!cboField
.RowSource = strSQL
.Requery
End With
End Sub
```

is working fine

```
strSQL = "SELECT table.field1 FROM table WHERE table.field2=1 And table.field2=2 And table.field2=3; "
```

is not working

Comment: The multiple conditions are not the issue. Please post your actual code with actual field names and parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A field cannot hold three different values. Try with:

```
… where table.field2 in (1, 2, 3);
```